# Does Excel support collapse/expand functionality?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to create structure similar to this one in Excel?

[image]

After click on expand button I want to see:

[image]

I investigated grouping functionality of Excel, but it looks differently for me.

Are there any options to have as demonstrated on screenshots?

Comment: With a pivot table you can do that quite easily

Comment: @Andreas are there any examples with pivot tables doing the same? I've seen a few forums, but didn't see any similar example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use grouping for this.

Select the rows/columns you want to group in this way and press ALT + SHIFT + RIGHT ARROW KEY to group.

*(ALT + SHIFT + LEFT removes the grouping)*

You can also find the option to group on the DATA tab.

You will be given a small button to press to hide/unhide the grouped Rows.

[image]

Comment: But this is not exactly what I want. With grouping we have some additional "-" button (not part of clickable "GROUPED ROWS")

Comment: you wont get exactly what you want, this or a pivot table are your only options